# parsing BLAST.xml with python-format required lower case string

Tags: python, xml, blast

Returns value error: Format required (lower case string) for line 25 in get_processor for searchIO_utils.py.
AtCBL1_CDS.txt is a file containing a protein sequence in fasta format.
I would like to know how to correctly access my BLAST output.

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
from Bio import SearchIO
#open query file as fasta_file
fasta_file= open("AtCBL1_CDS.txt").read()

#set up blast parameters
result = NCBIWWW.qblast ("blastp", "prot", fasta_file)


#run and create my_blast as output file
with open("my_blast.xml", "w") as out_handle:
    out_handle.write(result.read())

#close file
result.close()
out_handle.close()

result_handle=open("my_blast.xml")

blastp_result=SearchIO.read(result_handle)
print(blastp_result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to **SearchIO.read** should be a lowercase **format** parameter:

- *format* - lower case string denoting one of the supported formats. For instance *blast-xml* for XML blast format.

In your case the line should read:

```
blastp_result=SearchIO.read(result_handle,'blast-xml')
```